# Retrieve an array from FireStore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Very simple question but the other answers haven´t worked for me so I am asking this:
How can I retrieve an Array from Firestore look I got this:

```
noteRef = commentsRef.document(postKey);
noteRef.get().addOnSuccessListener( new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
        String postLikesString = documentSnapshot.getString("likes");
        postLikes = Integer.valueOf(postLikesString);
        postHasLiked = (ArrayList<String>) documentSnapshot.get("hasLiked");
    }
});
```

To test it I tried

```
postUsername = postHasLiked.get(0);
```

But that is telling me

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object
>   java.util.ArrayList.get(int)' on a null object reference

So has anybody got an Idea ?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure, `hasLiked` is the correct name for your key in Firestore? If so, perhaps try a list instead:
`List<String> postHasLiked = (List<String>) documentSnapshot.get("hasLiked");`. This seems to have worked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50233281/how-to-get-an-array-from-firestore).